# How do I switch to a new repository and make a new branch in that repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

Sorry if this is a very stupid question. I have spent the weekend trying to read up on how to use git but it just doesn't click with me (I also have a SLD which makes it harder to apply abstract solutions to specific problems). Also I find the jargon difficult, so apologies if I am explaining this badly.

I am trying to achieve two things:

1. I want to switch over to a new repository. I currently use one which is for my own personal work (repository A). I have some files that I want to add onto an existing public repository (repository B). I only want to add these files to Repository B, not repository A.
2. I want to make a new branch on repository B to add these files.

How do I do this?

Comment: Usually switch to new repository means you clone it (or init it) in a completely different directory somewhere else. Each A and B will have its own directory (working copy). Git command is smart and once in directory with A it will know its repository A and same for B.

Comment: Git's jargon *is* quite tricky. So are other jargon terms: what is an "SLD"? Ah: [SLD](https://www.cde.state.co.us/cdesped/sd-sld)  Anyway, with that said, it's worth noting that a *repository* is a collection of *commits:* not files, just commits. Each commit then contains some file(s). So if you create a new empty repository, it has no commits yet. If you copy ("clone") some existing repository, it usually has lots of commits in it.